# Duda Active Record

Tags: c#, sql, .net, servidor, activerecord

Estoy haciendo un trabajo para la universidad nos están introduciendo en el patron "Active Record" en C#. La cosa es que tengo una clase llamada `Persistente`, es digamos la clase base de la cual heredan todas las demás. Ésta contiene métodos como `obtenerConexion`, `ejecutarConsulta`,`traerTodo`,etc..

Se los dejo a continuación para que se guíen.

```
public abstract IEnumerable<object> traerTodo();



public SqlConnection obtenerConexion()
    {
        SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(Persistente.strConnection);
        if (conexion.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            conexion.Open();

        return conexion;
    }

public SqlDataReader ejecutarConsulta(SqlConnection conexion, string sql, List<SqlParameter> parametros, CommandType tipoComando, SqlTransaction transaction = null)
    {
        SqlDataReader ret = null;
        try
        {
            if (conexion != null)
            {
                SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(sql, conexion);
                if(parametros != null)
                {
                    comando.Parameters.AddRange(parametros.ToArray());
                }
                comando.CommandType = tipoComando;

                if (transaction != null)
                {
                    comando.Transaction = transaction;
                }

                if (conexion.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    conexion.Open();
                }

                ret = comando.ExecuteReader();

            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Yo por ejemplo estos métodos los utilizo de esta manera: Para el caso de querer agregar un cliente, creo el objeto, el mismo tiene un método guardar que es un `override` del guardar que tiene la clase base `Persistente`.

En su lógica creo el `string` sql, obtengo la conexión, creo la lista de parámetros y llamo a el método `ejecutarNoQuery` de la clase base, que es igual a el que les deje arriba solo cambia la devolución y poca cosa mas (Les cuento esto para que tengan una idea, de lo que hablo).

Pero en este caso yo quiero traer todos los clientes que tengo en mi base de datos, el tema es que para hacer dicho método el mismo debería ser de clase, por que la clase es la que administra a todos esos objetos `Cliente`, pero si lo hago de clase (`static`) pierdo el contacto con todos los métodos descritos arriba
`ejecutarConsulta` y `obtenerConexion`. Entonces sinceramente no se como hacerlo y me estoy volviendo loco, perdón por mi ignorancia es que estoy recién aprendiendo, si necesitan mas info o algo por favor avísenme y muchísimas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo los métodos `traerTodo()`, `obtenerConexion()` y `ejecutarConsulta()` esten la clase `ConexionImpl`, entonces intenta enviando la referencia de la clase al metodo `static` para poder realizar las consultas:

```
public class ServicioCliente
{
  public static IEnumerable<Cliente> ObtenerClientes()
  {
     // accedes a los metodo del la clase conexion por medio a la propiedad static
     var conexion = Conexion.Instancia.obtenerTodos();
  }
}
```

---

O puedes crear una propiedad estatica que te de la instancia de la clase conexion:

```
public abstract class Conexion
{
   public abstract IEnumerable<object> traerTodo();

   //...
   public static Conexion Instancia {
        get{
            return new ConexionImp();
        }
   }
}
```

Entonces para acceder a la conexión seria:

```
public class ServicioCliente
{
  public static IEnumerable<Cliente> ObtenerClientes()
  {
     // accedes a los metodo del la clase conexion por medio a la propiedad static
     var conexion = Conexion.Instancia.obtenerTodos();
  }
}
```

Nota que utilize el tipo `ConexionImpl`. Esto porque la clase base de conexión es abstracta y obviamente necesitaras una tipo concreta para crear una instancia.